# A Go endpoint to get all items from DynamoDB and return them as a JSON response

Tags: go, aws-cdk

Let me start by stating that I am currently in the process of learning Go and AWS CDK. What better way to learn than building a Serverless Todo API!? Using the Go AWS CDK (v2) I have built my infrastructure using the following AWS components:

1. API Gateway (HTTP)
2. AWS Lambda (Go)
3. DynamoDB

All [code is open-source](https://github.com/jwankhalaf/bash-todo). It is a Todo API, so I have a `Task` entity with some properties, these are:

```
type Task struct {
    TaskId    string `dynamodbav:"task_id" json:"task_id"`
    UserId    string `dynamodbav:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Content   string `dynamodbav:"content" json:"content"`
    CreatedAt string `dynamodbav:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    IsDone    bool   `dynamodbav:"is_done" json:"is_done"`
}
```

So far, I only have one endpoint coded. It is the `getitems` endpoint. This endpoint is responsible for returning all tasks from the database, here is the code:

```
package getitems

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func GetItemsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    const dynamodbTableNameEnvKey = "DYNAMODB_TABLENAME"

    dynamodbTableName, ok := os.LookupEnv(dynamodbTableNameEnvKey)

    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("the %v variable was not set!", dynamodbTableNameEnvKey)
    } else {
        log.Printf("The %v variable is set to: %v", dynamodbTableNameEnvKey, dynamodbTableName)
    }

    log.Println("Running the GetItemsHandler!")

    // using the sdk's default configuration, loading additional config
    // and credentials values from the environment variables, shared
    // credentials, and shared configuration files
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load sdk config, %v", err)
    }

    // using the config value, create the dynamodb client
    dynamodbService := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    var tasks []Task

    // build the required scan params
    scanInput := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String(dynamodbTableName),
    }

    response, err := dynamodbService.Scan(context.TODO(), scanInput)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("could not scan the dyanmodb table! error: %v", err)
    } else {
        err = attributevalue.UnmarshalListOfMaps(response.Items, &tasks)

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Couldn't unmarshal query response. Here's why: %v\n", err)
        }
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(tasks)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error happened in JSON marshal. Err: %s", err)
    }

    w.Write(jsonResponse)
}
```

Since I am new to Go, I suspect I am making some mistakes here, or perhaps I could improve things a little. The code right now "works", here is the response when I call the endpoint:

```
[{
    "task_id": "4d4b9d9f-760f-4f63-9b89-27750dfec9e2",
    "user_id": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589",
    "content": "Clean the car",
    "created_at": "2022-09-12T14:44:03Z",
    "is_done": false
}, {
    "task_id": "299c1283-5704-4170-8196-b43742007e4d",
    "user_id": "aae30f8e-aabe-4e38-918f-0f5a2223f589",
    "content": "Tidy the office",
    "created_at": "2022-09-12T14:42:38Z",
    "is_done": false
}]
```

Also, right now I have no tests and I'd like to know what should I be testing in this endpoint? And how can I write the tests (mocking ...etc). Right now, I have a `handler_test.go` file that simply has:

```
package getitems

import "testing"

func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
  got := "foo"
  want := "bar"

  if got != want {
    t.Errorf("got %q want %q", got, want)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, I'll admit to being a pedantic arse at times, but there's a few things that just jump out (in an OCD triggering kind of way) that I'll cover first:

There's some stylistic issues that kind of *"show"* that you're relatively new to golang. The official golang repo for the longest time had a list of [code review recommendations/comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) covering things beyond your standard `gofmt` stuff. One of those is naming, in particular stutter.

You have a package called `getitems`. A package starting with a verb just doesn't make sense. Functions are verbs, packages are, well, ... packages. Collections of functions and types (verbs and nouns if you will).

Changing the `package "getitems"` to `package "items"` makes a lot more sense, but then you have this `GetItems` function, which in turn leads to stutter in the form of: `items.GetItems`. This reads to me as *"from items, get items"*. Why not simply have `items.GetAll()`, which would read as *"get everything from items"*.

---

### Moving on

You are doing everything in a single handler function. Whether it be: getting config, connecting to a database, fetching data, converting/marshalling it, etc... This is really rather messy and above all: slow. It's much better to connect to the database in your `main` function, create a repository that takes this connection as a dependency, and expose some methods to get the data via this repository, and pass that on to your handler (which will be much more simplified as a result, and should only occupy itself with request/response actions).

As an added bonus, you no longer need to load the config and establish a DB connection *on every request*. AFAIK, the `dynamodb` package can be used concurrently. Considering you are dealing with `items` (which seem to be simple task objects), You can just have the repo object interact with dynamodb, scan the results into a `Task` type you declare in yet another package that your handler and repository packages both import, and as far as your handler is concerned: this is what it needs:

```
package handlers

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

type Repo interface {
    GetAll() ([]*Task, error)
    GetByID(id string) (*Task, error) // etc...
}

type svc struct {
    repo Repo
}

func New(r Repo) *svc {
    return &svc{
        repo: r,
    }
}

// GetItems. This is the handlers package, so GetItemsHandler is stutter
func (s *svc) GetItems(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tasks, err := s.repo.GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        // write error response
        return
    }
    resp, err := json.Marshal(tasks)
    if err != nil {
        // again: handle error
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(resp)
}
```

This, to my eye, is a hell of  a lot cleaner. It is also a lot easier to test. Simply mock the repository interface, inject the interface, and you can run tests where the repository returns the results you expect, an error, or no results at all, and ensure the handler behaves correctly. Because this handler can only marshal data returned by a dependency that returns a slice of `Task` objects, there's less errors to even consider. The list of maps unmarshalling is something handled by the repository, not the handler. The repository lives in its own package, so it handles errors at that point. It also means the handler can stay unchanged, should you move away from dynamodb. The repository would still expose the same methods, you'd just have to update its internals to cope with the new data source...

As for testing, like I mentioned above: you can mock the dependencies, but doing this all by hand is a right PITA. Below is a bare-bones example of how you can write this repository package. I've replaced the dynamodb dependency with a more generic interface for brevity sake, but the principles remain the same:

### Testing & Mocking

You have unit tests, which is great to see, but there's an issue IMO. A unit test, at its core, has to approach the code it tests as *"here's input X, I expect output Y. Dependencies that are used along the way should be called with argument Z, etc..."*. Essentially, unit tests should cover the API the tested unit provides/exposes. Golang allows you to ensure you do this by adding a `_test` suffix to the package name:

```
package foo

import (
    "errors"
)

var (
    InvalidSourceDataErr = errors.New("database returned incompatible data")
)

// Database is the interface this package needs - go packages declare their own dependency interfaces
type Database interface {
    Get() ([]any, error) // for example
}

type Data struct {} // some data-type this package deals with

type Repo struct {
    db Database
}

// New creates the instance the external world will use, pass in the dependency here (injection). Packages don't return interfaces in golang (generally speaking)
func New(db Database) *Repo {
    return &Repo{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (r *Repo) GetAll() ([]*Data, error) {
    all, err := r.db.Get() // get the data
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    dat := make([]*Data, 0, len(all))
    for _, v := range all {
        d, err := r.toData(v)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        dat = append(dat, d) // mapped to the expected type
    }
    return dat, nil
}

// converts data from DB (any) to the relevant type - error if fails
// this should not be exposed to the outside world
func (r *Repo) toData(v any) (*Data, error) {
    dm, ok := v.(map[string]any)
    if !ok {
        return nil InvalidSourceDataErr // can't map this
    }
    ret := Data{}
    // iterate over dm, map keys onto fields, if types don't match, return error
    return &ret, nil // mapping worked
}
```

For packages like this, you can use tools like mockgen to generate a mock `Database` interface like so:

```
//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -destination mocks/db_mock.go -package mocks your.module/path/to/foo Databse
type Database interface {
    Get() ([]any, error)
}
```

Now you can test this package like this:

```
package foo_test // _test suffix, so toData is not exposed even on the unit-test level

import (
    "testing"

    "your.module/path/to/foo" // import the package you're testing
    "your.module/path/to/foo/mocks" // import generated mocks

    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock" // mock stuff
)

type testFoo struct {
    *foo.Repo
    ctrl *gomock.Controller
    db   *mocks.MockDatabase // mocked dependency
}

func getRepo(t *testing.T) testFoo {
    t.Helper()
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    db := mocks.NewMockDatabase(ctrl)
    return testFoo{
        Repo: foo.New(db), // inject mock
        ctrl: ctrl,
        db:   db,
    }
}

func TestNoData(t *testing.T) {
    repo := getRepo(t)
    defer repo.ctrl.Finish() // signals gomock to check if the expected calls to the mocked dependencies have indeed been made
    // we specify what call we expect to be made, how many times to make it, and what to return
    repo.db.EXPECT().Get().Times(1).Return(nil, nil) // no error, no data
    got, err := repo.GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fail("Expected no errors, got one")
    }
    if len(got) > 0 {
        t.Fail("Expected nothing to be returned")
    }
}
```

To check the output of the function, check out packages like `require` or `assert`, so you can just write stuff like:

```
require.NoError(t, err)
require.Empty(t, got)
```

To test the private mapping function, you simply add tests where your mocked DB actually returns data:

```
func TestInvalidData(t *testing.T) {
    repo := getRepo(t)
    defer repo.ctrl.Finish()
    repo.db.EXPECT().Get().Times(1).Return([]interface{}{1}, nil) // 1 is not a map...
    got, err := repo.GetAll()
    require.Error(t, err)
    // or specifically, we expect this error:
    require.Equals(t, foo.InvalidSourceDataErr, err)
    require.Empty(t, got)
}

func TestValidData(t *testing.T) {
    repo := getRepo(t)
    defer repo.ctrl.Finish()
    repo.db.EXPECT().Get().Times(1).Return([]interface{}{map[string]interface{}}, nil) // populate map with valid data
    got, err := repo.GetAll()
    require.NoError(t, err) // this should not produce an error
    require.NotEmpty(t, got)
    // check values in the result, should match what we passed in through the mock
}
```

### Bringing it all together

So now we have: a handlers package, a repository package, and we have moved the initialisation of everything to the main function (ie we bootstrap everything at startup). Our main function would look something like this now:

```
func main() {
    ctx, cfunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cfunc()
    // add handler for kill/term signal to call cfunc
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // crash, log.Fatal, whatever
    }
    dyndb := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    repo := repository.New(dyndb) // create repo
    hdl := handlers.New(repo) // handler object
    // set up routing using `hdl.GetItems` for the route to get all etc..
}
```

Now we have one place to set up everything, one place to handle config, handlers that just read requests, and write responses, and a repository that makes it very clear (and easy) to see what a given handler does. The overal code is more efficient (as we no longer re-connect to dynamodb on each request), very easy to test, and a lot easier to maintain. The trade-off is that there's a bit more code to write if all you have is a single handler function, but the moment you add basic things like getting tasks by user id or by task ID, there's less duplication overall...